# Failed to upload image on localhost

Tags: localhost, xampp, windows

I am trying to edit my theme on a fresh installation via the customization page. When I try to upload the site logo via the media uploader, I get the following error:

> “logo.png” has failed to upload due to an error: Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2022/12. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

The site runs on my PC via XAMPP. I have given **all** permission to **every** user on the computer to the `wordpress` folder.

Although, the issue might be connected to the fact that I've edited the `httpd.conf` file to be able to serve sites from outside of the `htdocs` folder.

So instead of `C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress` my site runs from `E:/GitHub/wordpress`. The start pages opens in the browser. I can also access the admin page. But every time I try to upload an image, I get the error above.

I don't know if it's relevant, but here is a chunk of my `httpd.conf` file:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "E:/GitHub">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

...

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /github "E:/GitHub"
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From the message, it seems the user Apache/PHP are running as, can't write to the uploads directory.

Comment: @kero I've figured that, but how can I fix this error? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: This is server/Windows related, not really relevant to WP. Quick search brings up [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349469/changing-php-write-permissions-in-xampp-on-windows-7) and other topics. I have no familiarity with developing locally directly in Windows

Comment: @kero After reading the thread you've linked, something popped into my mind. The permission settings are fine. I just needed to restart the Apache server. Such a lame mistake on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the permission settings are fine. I just needed to restart the Apache server. This problem had nothing to do with the modification of the `httpd.conf` file.